# How to preserve registers in HLA Assembly

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, hla

I went ahead and wrote my code and the program works perfectly fine.

```
 program recursiveSubtractionProgram;
 #include( "stdlib.hhf" );
 static

    zA : int32;
    zB : int32;
    zResult : int32;

   procedure recursiveSubtraction( a: int32; b : int32 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
        static
            returnAddress : dword;
   begin recursiveSubtraction;
    pop(returnAddress);
    pop(zB);
    pop(zA);
    push(returnAddress);
    StartLoop:
    mov(zB, EBX);
    mov(zA, EAX);

    cmp(EBX, 0);
    je ValueA;
    cmp(EAX, 0);
    je ValueNegB;

    sub(1, EAX);
    sub(1, EBX);
    mov(EAX, zA);
    mov(EBX, zB);
    Call recursiveSubtraction;
    ValueA:
    mov(EAX, ECX);
    jmp zEnd;
    ValueNegB:
    neg(EBX);
    mov(EBX, ECX);
    jmp zEnd;

    zEnd:

    ret();
   end recursiveSubtraction;



 begin recursiveSubtractionProgram;
    stdout.put("Feed Me A: ");
    stdin.get(zA);
    stdout.put("Feed Me B: ");
    stdin.get(zB);
    push(zA);
    push(zB);
    call recursiveSubtraction;
    mov(ECX, zResult);
    stdout.put("RecursiveSubtraction of A-B = ",zResult);

 end recursiveSubtractionProgram;
```

When I turned in the assignment, my professor wrote

> Your Sorting Function Must Preserve The Registers BX, CX And DX Or Otherwise You May Get Register Corruption.

I'm not exactly sure what he means by this and how to fix it.

Comment: That is weird.  Does he normally use "BX" to mean EBX / RBX, rather than the low 16bits of that register?  More importantly, in all the usual x86 calling conventions (part of the ABI), ECX and EDX are not call-preserved.  Functions can use them as scratch registers without saving/restoring them.  Also, wait, why are you popping and re-pushing the return address?!?  It's cheaper to just read the values you want at an offset from ESP.  It's even worse that you're popping into memory, not registers.  Just leave the args on the stack until you want to read them, no need to copy.

Comment: Just push all the stuff you want to preserve, substract the base pointer by 32, execute your code and do the opposite of the first two again? You might want to also align the stack before executing your code.